# How much of Athlead did Jim Halpert own in The Office?

Tags: the-office

In the Office Jim invests $10,000 into a Sports Marketing Business with his friends in Philadelphia.  How much of Athlead did Jim buy/invest into?

Comment: How is this a 'trivia' question? What kinds of questions are 'allowed' on this site? Any opinion based ones would get removed for off topic. Not sure where else to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not known.**

There is no indication in the show how much Jim made from Athlead/Athleap.  The $10,000 investment is the only time money is really mentioned for the company.

With the information given; I don't think it's possible to determine a total portion of the company that Jim is supposed to own.  Even if we knew the other investment amounts, I don't think we could really tell what percentage Jim actually owned.  Jim had at least partially come up with the idea; and was working as a starting member in the company, so he likely got additional shares due to his crucial role.

In the final episode [Season 9 Episode 24/25](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2669746/), the Halpert's do not seem noticeably more wealthy than they did the year before.  To me this suggest one of three things:

- Jim did not make much off the sale of Athlead, when it was renamed to Athleap;
- Jim's shares transferred over from Athlead to Athleap; so he didn't really make a profit; but still has equity in the new company; or
- Jim made money when Athlead was sold; but it hasn't had a noticeable effect on their lifestyle.

Sadly this doesn't really tell us much about his share of the company.